# ref on react component is never called

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I upgraded from react 15 to react 16,
I tried this code, on a leaflet map:

```
<MarkerClusterGroup>
    <Marker
        position={[49.8397, 24.0297]}
        ref={(marker) => {
          console.log("marker", marker);
        }}
    />
    <Marker position={[52.2297, 21.0122]} />
    <Marker position={[51.5074, -0.0901]} />
</MarkerClusterGroup>
```

in react 15, log is printed, in react 16 nothing happens. 
it seems that ref function is never called.

what's the problem?

Comment: why are you trying to log it?

Comment: actually I try to pass the element itself (the ref) to store in array. I began testing with logging. I noticed that for some unknown reason, another components, such as popup , their ref is called with the relevant object.

Comment: does it have anything with states?

Comment: Does it not work if you do `ref={marker => this.refArray.push(marker)}`?

Comment: no, actually it says that property this.refArray doesn't exist.

Comment: yeah, you have to initialize it first in your constructor :) Like `this.refArray = []`

Comment: I tried to console.log(1) and it never prints a thing.

Comment: Not sure why you can't print. It should work. Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: no, actually it seems that for that component ref never called. after I debug it seems that this.refArray end with the value of []

Comment: Is Marker a functional or class component? Refs don't work with functional components

Comment: it seems that it is a class component: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/Marker.js

Comment: Hi I am facing the identical issue. My component is a class component but I do not use state in it, any new ideas?